# Qt Modal dialog without exec

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

In basically all relevant places I look, it says to avoid `exec` because it blocks the parent. There's also reports stating they should deprecate it. However I find myself practically unable to achieve my current task *without* exec.

For our company, I cloned a library which allows us to render reports and modified it to suit our needs (licenses were all checked), and within those changes was adjusting the variables so the user could input something for them. A couple of bugs/requests came up, and I moved away from `QMessageBox::getItem`/`getText`/`getDouble`/etc to my own implemented QDialog derivative.

```cpp
#include <QDialog>
#include "const.h"

namespace Ui {
   class VariableInput;
}

class VarInput : public QDialog {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   // constructor, couple of methods, etc
   void open();
private:
   Ui::VariableInput *ui;
}
```

Now, all of these documentations/user requests generally said to *avoid* using `exec`, so I attempted to find solutions which did not use it, not a single one of which could match what I needed to do. The variable dialogs get shown to the user, then saved to a cache so they dont get asked multiple times, and finally the report renders.

```cpp
bool DataManager::replaceVariables(QString query)
{
   // bunch of code checking for variable and extracting the name
   while (query.contains(variablemarker)) {
     QString name = "statically assigned for test purposes";
     VarInput inputDia;
     inputDia.setName(name);
     inputDia.setValue(getVarDefaultValue(name));
     inputDia.setType(getVarDataType(name))
     inputDia.open();
     if(inputDia.isCanceled) return false; //Cancel rendering
     m_cache.insert(name,inputDia.getValue()); 
     query.replace(name, inputDia.getValue());
   }
   return true;
}
```

Of course, all code shortened/condensed for relevancy.

I don't want to completely overhaul basically the entire library, simply so in this tiny instance I can use a slot in the `DataManager` so I can "loop" over the variables here, and assign a slot, especially given that I would currently simply reconstruct the thing over and over (currently: getting the variable in the real code is handled by a different function, which gets called in multiple places, if the user cancels, an error is thrown, which gets caught in this function and then false is returned; in the end it basically condenses down to this)

Our company told us to write "future proof" code as best as we can, so in an attempt to follow that, I wanted to avoid using `exec` instead opting for an `open` approach as Qt suggests. However, unless I rewrite basically the entire core library, I cannot simply open the input dialog, and then have the rendering proceed. I effectively **have to** block execution of the thread which handles the rendering.

I modified an existing dialog (which is in a similar situation) to use `ApplicationModal` and `open` which just causes it to flick in and out of existence for a split second. As far as I understand it, `open` doesn't spin up its own event loop, hence why it does that, I'd need to modify it (which would also be a massive rework) to make it respond to a slot in the outer object (the `DataManager` in this case), then somehow make the execution respond to wherever the function was originally called (the modified dialog gets called in around 10 different places for various reasons, the VarInput dialog would get called only in 4 different places) which would then continue the rendering process (somehow I'd have to pause that process too, since blocking the event loop is bad)

The only way I can see a dialog using `open`/`show` in a situation like this working out is a massive rework of the entire project, which is rather undesirable. I can also see other times when I'd be a similar situation where *not* blocking the event loop might be absolutely terrible for user experience and the programming effort required to do that (Things of the sort that Wireshark might do).

Why are some people so heavily discouraging the use of `exec` (when its literally the thing you use for the application start) and how would I get around it in a case like this, where I'm using a simple loop to replace the variables, blocking execution to allow the user to input the value?

Edit:
Some minimal examples that show the behavior (compiled locally using Qt6, C++17, with this CMakeLists: https://pastebin.com/GmMSy2Rr)

Code equivalent original: https://pastebin.com/wSh8Risu (Uses Qt's messagebox)

Code equivalent with exec: https://pastebin.com/VHYkzieQ (Custom messagebox, but using exec)

How would I achieve the same functionality using `open` or `show`

Comment: Your issue simply seems to be: 1. Start the execution of `someObject.someMethod`, 2. Show a Yes/No popup, the answer of which is required to complete the execution of `someObject.someMethod` and 3. resume the execution of `someObject.someMethod` using the answer obtained in 2. With that in mind, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (custom class + main = probably about 20 lines of code); this will make it easier to answer + to design a general principle instead of a solution working for a particular case.

Comment: @Atmo I added some minimal examples now

Comment: Can you clarify the problem(s) you have when you try to use `QDialog::open`?  As far as I can see `open` combined with `setModal` and connecting to the `finished` signal should be enough to 'mimic' the behaviour of `exec`.

Comment: @G.M. that may be the case for the behavior, but the execution isn't the same. Exec blocks the thread where the application runs, so I can get the "return" (or input) value in the same function. With just `open`+`setModal` thats not the case, I'd have a completely different function (the slot function) telling me what the return value is (which doesnt even get called from the original function where I start the dialog). Since I run this in a loop, I'd have to also pause the loop, which in turn means I have to stop the rendering, etc - i.e. the massive rewrite Im talking about

Comment: The minimal example I gave (in the pastebin) also shows that behavior, the execution _depends_ on the return value of the Dialog (though the value of the dialog is constant and only gets logged out making it seem rather useless, in the actual code that's not the case). With a finished slot, I might be able to add it to the cache, but the user would then have 5 open dialogues asking for an input or the thing would have to be recursive, in which case I'd have to pass a ton of extra information along, and rewrite the entire rendering engine

Comment: You may not have understood what `exec()` blocks. As stated in the help (and that part, you have understood), `exec()` starts an event loop for the dialog. What that event loop blocks is not another widget or, as you wrote a "parent" of some sort; what it blocks is the application's loop (aka the event loop in what we call the main thread). As such, your example is a poor one is because you call `QDialog::exec()` before you even started the loop with `QApplication::exec()`. Without that main loop started, a non-blocking call to `QDialog::show()` makes no sense.

Comment: Quote from [QApplication::exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#exec) to supplement my previous comment: *Generally, no user interaction can take place before calling exec(). As a special case, modal widgets like QMessageBox can be used before calling exec(), because modal widgets call exec() to start a local event loop.* And indeed, the only thing you can call before starting the main event loop is `exec()` on a modal window (i.e. **not** `show()`).

Comment: I think the fact you are struggling whereas @G.M. or I do not see any problem with replacing `exec()` by `show()` comes from that initial misconception: before calling `QApplication::exec()`, it makes no sense to call `show()`, after calling `QApplication::exec()`, using `show()` instead of `exec()` only requires a minimal amount of work.

Comment: @Atmo Ah, that makes sense. Okay, I will adjust the example to better represent what I have

Answer (score 0):

As I hope I clarified in the comments, your issue comes from a misunderstanding that you can call `QDialog::show()` before starting the main event loop, in `QApplication::exec()`.

This is not how it works. The only widget you can call before starting the event loop is a modal message box displayed with `exec()`, as stated in the [assistant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#exec).

Replacing `QDialog::exec()` by `QDialog::show()` is trivial when inside the event loop. You simply have to:

1. Take the code that contains `QDialog::exec()`.
2. Move everything that needs the result of `exec()` into a slot.
3. Connect that slot to the `finished` signal of your messsage box.
4. Substitute `exec` for `show`

The below example demonstrates this method. See `MyWidget::execMsgBox` vs `MyWidget::showMsgBox`, with the 2 ways  `MyWidget::handleMessageBoxResult` is called to use the result.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>


class MyWidget : public QWidget {
public:
    MyWidget() : QWidget(nullptr) {
        label = new QLabel("You clicked nothing yet", this);
        label->setMinimumWidth(280);
        QPushButton* execButton = new QPushButton("Exec", this);
        execButton->move(4, 30);
        QPushButton* showButton = new QPushButton("Show", this);
        showButton->move(84, 30);

        connect(execButton, &QAbstractButton::clicked,
                this, &MyWidget::execMsgBox);
        connect(showButton, &QAbstractButton::clicked,
                this, &MyWidget::showMsgBox);
    }
    void execMsgBox()
    {
        QMessageBox* msgBox = createMsgBox("Exec dialog");
        int result = msgBox->exec();
        handleMsgBoxResult(result);
    }
    void showMsgBox()
    {
        QMessageBox* msgBox = createMsgBox("Show dialog");
        msgBox->setModal(true);
        connect(msgBox, &QMessageBox::finished,
                this, &MyWidget::handleMsgBoxResult);
        msgBox->show();
    }
protected:
    QMessageBox* createMsgBox(const QString title)
    {
        return new QMessageBox(
            QMessageBox::Icon::NoIcon,
            title,
            "Click yes or no",
            QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No
        );
    }
    void handleMsgBoxResult(int result)
    {
        switch (result) { //With exec, default is never reached.
        case QMessageBox::No:  label->setText("You clicked no."); break;
        case QMessageBox::Yes: label->setText("You clicked yes."); break;
        default: label->setText("You closed the message box without answering."); 
        }
    }
private:
    QLabel* label;
};

int main(int argc, char** arga)
{
    QApplication a(argc, arga);

    MyWidget w;
    w.show();
    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Well, this is the issue that I talked about, I need the result in the original function - in your example, that'd be in showMsgBox, having the result in a different function doesn't allow me to substitute the variables in the loop, without the said massive rewrite. As I said, Ill provide a more accurate example thought that will necessarily be bigger

Comment: I was in a little bit of a hurry before, have refactored the code just now. The version I originally wrote made the change look bigger than what it needed to be.